# PCWSTR vs LPWSTR

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, interop

It is my understanding (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that the only difference between them is whether the string might be modified by the called function. ([PCWSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#PCWSTR) , [LPWSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#LPWSTR))

I am now trying to pass a string from C# to a function expecting a **PCWSTR**, but all I can find is `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`. Am I correct that that is fine? (Yes, it *works*. That, though, is not a proof that it's fine. Some things *work* but then cause memory leaks etc.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PCWSTR is a time anachronism, dinosaur-and-humans movie style.  Finding a 16-bit program that uses short pointers on a Unicode string is like finding a white elephant.  Only the distinct between LPCWSTR and LPWSTR is meaningful.

The C in LPCWSTR is simply annotation for *const*, a C language keyword.  It promises that the called function never modifies the string that you pass.  Which is very important to know in that language, it is not safe to pass a string literal to a LPWSTR argument.  That is very likely to crash the program when it tries to update the string and fails because the memory page is read-only.

And it matters when you pinvoke.  Passing a System.String to a LPCWSTR argument is fine, strings are immutable in .NET so you'll get a guarantee that an interned string literal isn't going to get mangled.  A very hard to diagnose problem.  Using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` explicitly should not be necessary in general, you'd use the CharSet.Auto property in the [DllImport] attribute and get the LPWStr marshaling for free.

But if the argument type is LPWSTR then you **must** pass a StringBuilder instead.  With a sufficient Capacity to allow the native code to poke around in the builder buffer to write the string.

Answer (score 3):

A function taking a `PCWSTR` parameter can't use that parameter to modify the characters of the string, unlike a function that takes a `LPWSTR` parameter. Each character of the string is stored as `WCHAR`.

`UnmanagedType.LPWStr` is the right marshalling type for such a string.

Comment: Both PCWSTR and LPWSTR use a WCHAR to store a character. That's the "W" in their name.